# How to add a custom view just below nav bar in a tableview controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create an interface like this

[image]

Where I have a piece of torn paper with drop shadow that sits below the nav bar but above my tableview.

I use the following code in my tableview controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"ripped-paper"]]];
}
```

This works fine except the ripper paper scrolls with the table view. I require it to stay fixed under the navbar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 6, you can just use the `shadowImage` property of [`UINavigationBar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html).

```
UIImage *image = [[image imageNamed:@"tornPaper"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(/* Your insets here */)];
self.navigationItem.navigationBar.shadowImage = image;
```

Comment: Do you mean store the size before rotating?

Comment: No, I mean you can set the image you want with 1 line of code and it just works. Just use an image that's wide enough to work on landscape on a 4" screen, or set a resizable image. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and add your image to the table view controller `self.view.superview`:

```
    [self.view.superview addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"ripped-paper"]]];
```

You should execute this in `viewDidAppear`, though (otherwise self.view.superview will not be set yet).

This could require also changing the frame/center, more or less like this:

```
  UIImageView* rippedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"ripped-paper"]];
  rippedView.center = <SET CENTER HERE>;
  [self.view.superview addSubview:rippedView];
```

But in the end it will greatly depend on your view hierarchy.

EDIT:

for your autorotation issue, try to set the view autoresizingMaks

```
rippedView.autoresizingMaks = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

and see if things improve. That way, the image view should not be resized on rotation. (Also: are you doing anything in your rotation method?)

Comment: The ripped paper needs to sit over the tableview for the transparency to work

Comment: then you could add it to the superview and set its center so that it works like you need. I will remove the reference to navigation bar background from my answer.

Comment: Looking good! My issue now is that when phone rotates, the height of the rippedView increases to 90% of the screen! I've defined it like so 


`UIImageView* rippedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"ripped-paper"]];


rippedView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f , 0.0f, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 15.0f);`

Comment: sorry that didn't work :( no i'm not doing anything when rotating

Comment: could you just try and log your rippedView frame before and after rotating?